# How do I change a switch size in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to increase the size of the `react-bootstrap` switch but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried reading the docs and looking it up but I couldn't find any other way apart from changing the bootstrap css directly.
Here's the code:

```
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

function SwitchExample() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Check 
        type="switch"
        id="custom-switch"
        label="Check this switch"
      />
    </Form>
  );
}

export default SwitchExample;
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change switch size in css

```
.form-switch .form-check-input {width: 4em; height: 2em;}
```

and import css file to your project